# emails sent by a phantom job: find a sender job

Tags: sql-server-agent

Every night at the same time I receive some mails like that:
`DESCRIPTION: Error: 50000 Severity: 16 State: 1 [ERROR]:DWHDumpProcess_XXX job is either failed or not in good state. Please check. Return Code (null)`
sent by different DWH SQL servers.

The problem is what there is no job on the server which has a name DWHDumpProcess_XXX. I've checked all mail-related tables in MSDB and can't find a possibility to find a job which sends an information.
Do one of you have an idea how I can verify the sender? (accordingly to the email header it's an SQL server in question, not a SMTP-faked email)

Comment: Check your logs. If the DB is sending out emails, then it probably crying for help and wants you to look at something.

Comment: I would check msdb.dbo.sysmail_sentitems to be sure that it was sent from this SQL server.

select top 100 * from msdb.dbo.sysmail_sentitems where body like '%DWHDumpProcess%'

Also, it's worth to check if there is such message in sys.messages table.

Comment: I could be mistaken, but I don't believe `sysmail_sentitems` logs Notification Emails on Job failures. Have you actually checked the SQL Server Agent - Jobs to see if there's one with a similar name to the error email you received? Otherwise, as Michael suggests, check your Log file which should essentially be a text file stored in the directory where your SQL instance is installed to.

Comment: Error 50000 is not a system message, but a hand-written one. I wouldn't take any of the wording too literally. Could `DWHDumpProcess_XXX` be a stored procedure or some other concept of "job" that isn't a SQL Agent job?

Comment: @AndreySamykin, I've checked all *mail* tables and sys.messages: SQL agent sent an email, no one SQL job has a title similar to the mentioned in the email. No custom messages defined.

Comment: Did you check if there is a SQL Agent alert configured to notify an operator by email when error number 50000 occurs?

Comment: @EricPrévost, SQL server is configured to notify if severity 16 occures, that's enough (correct me please if I'm wrong)

Comment: @AMtwo, thank you for the point with 50000 as hand-written message, that is something I missed indeed! There is no one database expect SSIS on this server, no additional SPs so I pass this problem to the development to check a code.